# Why is "&&" being used in closure arguments?

Tags: reference, rust, borrowing

I have two questions regarding [this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find):

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];

assert_eq!(a.iter().find(|&&x| x == 2), Some(&2));
assert_eq!(a.iter().find(|&&x| x == 5), None);
```

1. Why is `&&x` used in the closure arguments rather than just `x`? I understand that `&` is passing a reference to an object, but what does using it twice mean?

   I don't understand what the documentation says:

   > Because `find()` takes a reference, and many iterators iterate over references, this leads to a possibly confusing situation where the argument is a double reference. You can see this effect in the examples below, with `&&x`.
2. Why is `Some(&2)` used rather than `Some(2)`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`a` is of type `[i32; 3]`; an array of three `i32`s.
`[i32; 3]` does not implement an `iter` method, but it *does* dereference into `&[i32]`.
[`&[i32]` implements an `iter` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) which produces an iterator.
[This iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) implements `Iterator<Item=&i32>`.

It uses `&i32` rather than `i32` because the iterator has to work on arrays of *any* type, and not all types can be safely copied.  So rather than restrict itself to copyable types, it iterates over the elements by reference rather than by value.

[`find` is a method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) defined for all `Iterator`s.  It lets you look at each element and return the one that matches the predicate.  Problem: if the iterator produces non-copyable values, then passing the value into the predicate would make it impossible to return it from `find`.  The value cannot be re-generated, since iterators are not (in general) rewindable or restartable.  Thus, `find` has to pass the element to the predicate by-reference rather than by-value.

So, if you have an iterator that implements `Iterator<Item=T>`, then `Iterator::find` requires a predicate that takes a `&T` and returns a `bool`.  `[i32]::iter` produces an iterator that implements `Iterator<Item=&i32>`.  Thus, `Iterator::find` called on an array iterator requires a predicate that takes a `&&i32`.  That is, it passes the predicate a pointer to a pointer to the element in question.

So if you were to write `a.iter().find(|x| ..)`, the type of `x` would be `&&i32`.  This cannot be directly compared to the literal `i32` value `2`.  There are several ways of fixing this.  One is to explicitly dereference `x`: `a.iter().find(|x| **x == 2)`.  The other is to use pattern matching to destructure the double reference: `a.iter().find(|&&x| x == 2)`.  These two approaches are, in this case, doing *exactly* the same thing. [1]

As for why `Some(&2)` is used: because `a.iter()` is an iterator over `&i32`, *not* an iterator of `i32`.  If you look at the documentation for `Iterator::find`, you'll see that for `Iterator<Item=T>`, it returns an `Option<T>`.  Hence, in this case, it returns an `Option<&i32>`, so that's what you need to compare it against.

---

[1]: The differences only matter when you're talking about non-`Copy` types.  For example, `|&&x| ..` wouldn't work on a `&&String`, because you'd have to be able to move the `String` out from behind the reference, and that's not allowed.  However, `|x| **x ..` *would* work, because that is just reaching inside the reference without moving anything.

Comment: thanks! Additionally, in case if anyone doesn't understand what is ***"dereference into ```&[i32]```"***, an array ```a``` can be automatically borrowed as a slice ```&a``` according to [this](http://rustbyexample.com/primitives/array.html),

Answer (score 4):

1) I thought the book explanation was good, maybe my example with `.cloned()` below will be useful. But since `.iter()` iterates over references, you have to specify reference additionally because `find` expects a reference.

2) `.iter()` is iterating over references; therefore, you find a reference.

You could use `.cloned()` to see what it would look like if you didn't have to do deal with references:

```
assert_eq!(a.iter().cloned().find(|&x| x == 2), Some(2));
```