# Can't compare `&Thing` with `Thing`

Tags: rust, mocking

I know what the error means, but I can't fix it. I'm using `mockers` to test my work and I got stuck when trying to verify the struct parameter which was given to a mocked trait's function. The simplified code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate mockers;
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate mockers_derive;

#[cfg(test)]
use mockers_derive::mocked;

#[derive(Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Thing {
    pub key: String,
    pub class: String,
}

#[cfg_attr(test, mocked)]
pub trait DaoTrait {
    fn get(&self, thing: &Thing) -> String;
}

struct DataService {
    dao: Box<DaoTrait>,
}

impl DataService {
    pub fn get(&self, thing: &Thing) -> String {
        self.dao.get(thing)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    use mockers::matchers::eq;
    use mockers::Scenario;

    #[test]
    fn my_test() {
        use mockers::matchers::check;
        let scenario = Scenario::new();
        let mut dao = scenario.create_mock_for::<DaoTrait>();
        let thing = Thing {
            key: "my test".to_string(),
            class: "for test".to_string(),
        };

        scenario.expect(
            dao.get_call(check(|t: &Thing| t.to_owned() == thing))
                .and_return("hello".to_string()),
        );
        let testee = DataService { dao: Box::new(dao) };

        let rtn = testee.get(&thing);
        assert_eq!(rtn, "hello");
    }
}
```

I got the errors:

```
warning: unused import: `mockers::matchers::eq`
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
33 |     use mockers::matchers::eq;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

error[E0277]: can't compare `&Thing` with `Thing`
  --> src/main.rs:47:57
   |
47 |             dao.get_call(check(|t: &Thing| t.to_owned() == thing))
   |                                                         ^^ no implementation for `&Thing == Thing`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<Thing>` is not implemented for `&Thing`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `mockers::matchers::BoolFnMatchArg<Thing, [closure@src/main.rs:47:32: 47:65 thing:_]>: mockers::MatchArg<&Thing>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:47:17
   |
47 |             dao.get_call(check(|t: &Thing| t.to_owned() == thing))
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `mockers::MatchArg<&Thing>` is not implemented for `mockers::matchers::BoolFnMatchArg<Thing, [closure@src/main.rs:47:32: 47:65 thing:_]>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <mockers::matchers::BoolFnMatchArg<T, F> as mockers::MatchArg<T>>
```

I viewed `check`'s source code :

```
pub fn check<T, F: Fn(&T) -> bool>(f: F) -> BoolFnMatchArg<T, F> {
    BoolFnMatchArg { func: f, _phantom: PhantomData }
}
```

I think the closure `|t: &Thing| t.to_owned() == thing` I had given is right. I also tried the following closures, but none of them worked.

```
|t: &Thing| t == &thing
```

```
|t: &Thing| *t == thing
```

```
|t: Thing| t == thing
```

The Cargo.toml:

```
[dev-dependencies]
mockers = "0.12.1"
mockers_derive = "0.12.1"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot compare a `Thing` to a `&Thing` using the default derivation of `PartialEq`:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Thing(String);

fn main() {
    let t_val = Thing(String::new());
    let t_ref = &t_val;

    t_val == t_ref;
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:14
  |
8 |     t_val == t_ref;
  |              ^^^^^ expected struct `Thing`, found &Thing
  |
  = note: expected type `Thing`
             found type `&Thing`
```

To fix that error, you need to do one of two things:

1. Match the reference level:

   - `t_val == *t_ref`
   - `&t_val == t_ref`
2. Implement equality for a mismatched number of references:

   ```
   impl<'a> PartialEq<&'a Thing> for Thing {
       fn eq(&self, other: &&'a Thing) -> bool {
           self == *other
       }
   }

   impl<'a> PartialEq<Thing> for &'a Thing {
       fn eq(&self, other: &Thing) -> bool {
           *self == other
       }
   }
   ```

---

However, none of that solves *your actual problem*. You've misunderstood how the mockers library works; your closure is taking the wrong level of reference, and it needs to take ownership of the value to compare:

```
let expected_thing = thing.clone();
scenario.expect(
    dao.get_call(check(move |t: &&Thing| t == &&expected_thing))
        .and_return("hello".to_string()),
);
```

Comment: It worked, but the double && I can't understand, would you like to give me some guidance?

Comment: I found an explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828013/why-is-being-used-here

Answer (score 3):

The first thing (pun not intended) to notice is that `t.to_owned()` produces a `&Thing`, not a `Thing` as you might have expected. That's because `Thing` doesn't implement `Clone`, and therefore it doesn't implement [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) either (because there is a blanket impl that implements `ToOwned` for all `Clone` types), which provides the [`to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned) method. But then why does the call still work? Because references implement `Clone`, so `&Thing` implements `ToOwned`! This gives `to_owned` this signature:

```
fn to_owned(self: &&Thing) -> &Thing;
```

You can fix this by deriving `Clone` for `Thing`.

However, you don't *need* to clone the `Thing` in order to compare it. You can instead compare two references to `Thing` (e.g. by writing `|t: &Thing| t == &thing`). [`PartialEq::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq) (which the `==` operator translates to) takes its arguments by reference, and [references implement `PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.1/src/core/cmp.rs.html#929-934) by peeling off a layer of references (i.e. they don't compare the pointer values, unlike raw pointer types).

Comment: Thanks, I derived `Clone` for `Thing`, but the clousour `` does not work yet. I got error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `mockers::matchers::BoolFnMatchArg<Thing, [closure@src\lib.rs:46:32: 46:65 thing:_]>: mockers::MatchArg<&Thing>` is not satisfied

Comment: I also tried `|t: &Thing| t == &thing` without derive `Clone` before your answer.  It just does not work!

Comment: Shame on me for answering without testing!