# What are the differences between using * and & to compare values for equality?

Tags: rust

I think I understand, at a very high level what the difference between `&` and `*` in Rust is as it pertains to memory management.

What is the difference between the following code snippets.  Are there dangers to applying one approach versus the other?

```
for (i, item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
    if *item == b' ' {
        return i;
    }
}
```

```
for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
    if item == b' ' {
        return i;
    }
}
```

```
for (i, item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
    if item == &b' ' {
        return i;
    }
}
```

As I understand it, when I return a value from `iter()` I am returning a reference to the element found in `bytes`. If I want to make a comparison on the item, I need to either compare between two references `&u8` or I need to make `&item` a reference itself so that when I call `item` it is of type `u8`, or I need to dereference `item` when I compare it so that `item` = `&u8` -> `*item` = `u8`.

1. When I run the code using `(i, &item)`, when I call `item` later on, is this exactly the same thing as dereferencing in the second example, or is there a fundamental difference about how the compiler is interpreting the first code snippet and the second code snippet?
2. Is there anything wrong with the third code snippet? I realize this is a bit of an opinion based question.  I realize that if I were to assign a value to another variable using `item` (or `*item`, or assigning the value as a reference) I would have different datatypes being returned later on.  Aside from managing your data types, is there anything else to keep in mind when considering if `item == &b' '` is the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference, whatsoever, between these snippets. They generate the **exact same assembly**:

```
pub fn a(bytes: &[u8]) -> usize {
    for (i, item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if *item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }
    0
}

pub fn b(bytes: &[u8]) -> usize {
    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }
    0
}

pub fn c(bytes: &[u8]) -> usize {
    for (i, item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == &b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }
    0
}
```

```
playground::a:
    negq    %rsi
    movq    $-1, %rax

.LBB0_1:
    leaq    (%rsi,%rax), %rcx
    cmpq    $-1, %rcx
    je  .LBB0_2
    cmpb    $32, 1(%rdi,%rax)
    leaq    1(%rax), %rax
    jne .LBB0_1
    retq

.LBB0_2:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq

; The code is identical so the functions are aliased
.set playground::b, playground::a
.set playground::c, playground::a
```

For what it's worth, I'd write the function as

```
pub fn a(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    bytes.iter().position(|&b| b == b' ')
}
```

> `iter()` [...] a reference to the element found in `bytes`

Yes, `iter` is typically a function that returns an iterator of references.

> I need to either compare between

Generally, you need to compare between two things [with the same amount of references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52656800/155423) or sometimes one level of reference difference. How you achieve this is immaterial — referencing a value or dereferencing another, or dereferencing via `*` as an expression or via `&` in a pattern.

See also:

- [Can't compare `&Thing` with `Thing`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52656800/155423)

Comment: Even easier to use `bytes.iter().position(|&b| b == b' ')`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach good point! I just went to the chained form and stopped there ;-)