# Is Vec<&&str> the same as Vec<&Str>?

Tags: rust, reference

I'm learning Rust and I'm trying to solve an advent of code challenge (day 9 2015).

I created a situation where I end up with a variable that has the type `Vec<&&str>` (note the double '&', it's not a typo). I'm now wondering if this type is different than `Vec<&str>`. I can't figure out if a reference to a reference to something would ever make sense. I know I can avoid this situation by using `String` for the `from` and `to` variables. I'm asking if `Vec<&&str> == Vec<&str>` and if I should try and avoid `Vec<&&str>`.

Here is the code that triggered this question:

```
use itertools::Itertools
use std::collections::{HashSet};

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("input.txt").unwrap();

    let mut vertices: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {

        let data: Vec<&str> = line.split(" ").collect();

        let from = data[0];
        let to = data[2];

        vertices.insert(from);
        vertices.insert(to);
    }

    // `Vec<&&str>` originates from here
    let permutations_iter = vertices.iter().permutations(vertices.len());

    for perm in permutations_iter {
        let length_trip = compute_length_of_trip(&perm);
    }
}

fn compute_length_of_trip(trip: &Vec<&&str>) -> u32 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "&&" being used in closure arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828013/why-is-being-used-in-closure-arguments)

Comment: @Caesar The linked Q&A explain why the double reference arises. The OP here understands that (or at least doesn't ask about that), but asks whether the resulting `Vec<&&str>` is equivalent to `Vec<&str>` and whether it should be avoided for some reason. That's a different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Are Vec<&str> and Vec<&&str> different types?

> I'm now wondering if this type is different than `Vec<&str>`.

Yes, a `Vec<&&str>` is a type different from `Vec<&str>` - you can't pass a `Vec<&&str>` where a `Vec<&str>` is expected and vice versa. `Vec<&str>` stores string slice references, which you can think of as pointers to data inside some strings. `Vec<&&str>` stores references to such string slice references, i.e. pointers to pointers to data. With the latter, accessing the string data requires an additional indirection.

However, Rust's auto-dereferencing makes it possible to *use* a `Vec<&&str>` much like you'd use a `Vec<&str>` - for example, `v[0].len()` will work just fine on either, `v[some_idx].chars()` will iterate over chars with either, and so on. The only difference is that `Vec<&&str>` stores the data more indirectly and therefore requires a bit more work on each access, which can lead to slightly less efficient code.

Note that you can always convert a `Vec<&&str>` to `Vec<&str>` - but since doing so requires allocating a new vector, if you decide you don't want `Vec<&&str>`, it's better not to create it in the first place.

#### Can I avoid Vec<&&str> and how?

Since a `&str` is `Copy`, you can avoid the creation of `Vec<&&str>` by adding a `.copied()` when you iterate over `vertices`, i.e. change `vertices.iter()` to `vertices.iter().copied()`. If you don't need `vertices` sticking around, you can also use `vertices.into_iter()`, which will give out `&str`, as well as free `vertices` vector as soon as the iteration is done.

The reason why the additional reference arises and the ways to avoid it have been [covered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828013/why-is-being-used-in-closure-arguments) before.

#### Should I avoid Vec<&&str>?

There is nothing inherently wrong with `Vec<&&str>` that would require one to avoid it. In most code you'll never notice the difference in efficiency between `Vec<&&str>` and `Vec<&str>`. Having said that, there are some reasons to avoid it beyond performance in microbenchmarks. The additional indirection in `Vec<&&str>` requires the exact `&str`s it was created from (and not just the strings that own the data)  to stick around and outlive the new collection. This is not relevant in your case, but would become noticeable if you wanted to return the permutations to the caller that owns the strings. Also, there is value in the simpler type that doesn't accumulate a reference on each transformation. Just imagine needing to transform the `Vec<&&str>` further into a new vector - you wouldn't want to deal with `Vec<&&&str>`, and so on for every new transformation.

Regarding performance, less indirection is usually better since it avoids an extra memory access and increases data locality. However, one should also note that a `Vec<&str>` takes up 16 bytes per element (on 64-bit architectures) because a slice reference is represented by a "fat pointer", i.e. a pointer/length pair. A `Vec<&&str>` (as well as `Vec<&&&str>` etc.) on the other hand takes up only 8 bytes per element, because a reference to a fat reference is represented by a regular "thin" pointer. So if your vector measures millions of elements, a `Vec<&&str>` might be *more* efficient than `Vec<&str>` simply because it occupies less memory. As always, if in doubt, measure.

Comment: Reading the title of the question, I thought a pretty short answer would suffice. Then I saw your long answer and after I read it, I was impressed (once again) how informative your answers are!

Comment: Thanks. The parts on the auto-dereferencing and on the lifetime of the references was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have `&&str` is that the data `&str` is owned by vertices and when you create an interator over that data you are simply getting a reference to that data, hence the `&&str`.

There's really nothing to avoid here. It simply shows your iterator references the data that is inside the HashSet.